# config.fullPage = true; is not working in ckeditor inline mode. How to achieve that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor inline mode. When i enter some html code  by clicking on source button and after closing it when i reopen by clicking on source button only content inside body tag is been showing.

I have searched in ckeditor forums that all these html and body tags can be seen using configuration setting

config.fullPage = true;

I tried but that didn't work. Can someone please tell me why it was not working with inline mode.

Here is my configuration setting:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

    // %REMOVE_START%
    // The configuration options below are needed when running CKEditor from source files.
    config.fullPage = true;
    config.plugins = 'dialogui,dialog,about,a11yhelp,dialogadvtab,basicstyles,bidi,blockquote,clipboard,button,panelbutton,panel,floatpanel,colorbutton,colordialog,menu,contextmenu,div,resize,toolbar,elementspath,enterkey,entities,popup,filebrowser,find,fakeobjects,flash,floatingspace,listblock,richcombo,font,format,horizontalrule,htmlwriter,iframe,wysiwygarea,image,indent,indentblock,indentlist,smiley,justify,link,list,liststyle,magicline,maximize,newpage,pagebreak,pastetext,pastefromword,preview,print,removeformat,save,selectall,showblocks,showborders,sourcearea,specialchar,menubutton,scayt,stylescombo,tab,table,tabletools,undo,wsc,sourcedialog,tokens';
    config.skin = 'moono';
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '../kcfinder/browse.php?type=images';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '../kcfinder/upload.php?type=images';
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.scayt_autoStartup = true;
    config.baseFloatZIndex = 900;
    config.removePlugins = 'youtube';
    config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'tokens'},
    { name: 'others' }
];
```

Comment: this is not java, but javascript

Comment: Sorry question got saved before typing javascript

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because it can't work. In full page mode you can edit entire document, so where and how would you like to load CKEditor there if all that has to be inline?

Comment: I'm loading ckeditor on a div and triggering inline mode when user clicks on div area. By clicking on source button user can enter html code. When again if i open i need to show the full content is that possible.

Comment: Any reference please why this is not possible through inline mode